# Should I split timestamp parts into separate columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, optimization, timestamp, query-performance

I am building a PostgreSQL database and I have created a `timestamp` table, where the primary key is the timestamp itself (e.g. `id: Fri Apr 13 2018 15:00:19`). The database is supposed to be later migrated to a data warehouse, from which analytics will be extracted.

At this point, I am wondering whether it is beneficial to **add extra columns** to the `timestamp` table, containing the parsed metrics such as the example below, **or have a single table with the ID's**.

```
id                       | year | month | day | hour | minutes | seconds
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fri Apr 13 2018 15:00:19 | 2018 |   4   | 13  |  15  |    0    |   19


vs


id
-------------------------
Fri Apr 13 2018 15:00:19
```

My goal is to achieve the best performance possible when querying the data warehouse, so I'm **assuming** having the timestamp split accordingly will result in faster queries rather than unzipping time metrics in real-time:

```
SELECT * FROM timestamp_table WHERE year = 2018 /* Querying values already parsed */

vs

SELECT * FROM timestamp_table WHERE YEAR(timestamp_id) = 2018 /* Parsing in real-time*/
```

I would appreciate some *best practices* input on this.

Comment: The records aren't supposed to be updated, each one maps to an occurrence in a webpage, therefore it makes sense to have static records and timestamps

Answer (score 6):

Keep the timestamp and don't add columns for the parts.

If you need to search for part of a timestamp, you can always create indexes on `extract` expressions.

Having individual columns wastes space and adds undesirable redundancy for no benefit I can envision.

Comment: In that case should I have a separate table or have the timestamp object inside each table? Also, is it not ok to have some redundancy if that's gonna (positively) impact performance when querying the data?

Comment: Normally you shouldn't store the same information redundantly. If you get a notable performance benefit, exceptions are ok. If that is the case for storing the same timestamps in several tables depends on your data model and your queries. But I am quite sure that you won't get a performance benefit from storing the several parts of a timestamp separately.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be engaging in premature optimization -- you should not *assume* performance characteristics of any particular design, but test them.

When you store components of a timestamp value in separate columns you may not gain noticeable performance benefits, but you *will* increase the risk of inconsistent data or the maintenance overhead (or both).

Having said that, there *may be* valid reasons to store *some* components of the timestamp as separate columns, for example:

- Components, such as year, quarter, month constitute valid dimensions in your data warehouse model.
- Your database physical design calls for data partitioning by time intervals to facilitate maintenance or improve performance of some operations.